# Changing the speed at which an object drops when affected by gravity.(SpriteKit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have an object that needs to fall down the scene when the game starts. When the player taps the screen the object moves back to the top of the scene. In order to make the object fall I set it to be affected by gravity. This works fine but the problem is the object falls down the screen to fast. Can I set the speed at which the object falls do to gravity to a different speed. If so how do I do this.

Comment: You can set the `gravity` vector to something less than `-9.8`. [`SCNPhysicsWorld`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsWorld_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNPhysicsWorld/gravity)

Comment: Before you get a few down-votes, you should 1) Try it yourself, and if you have done that, post what you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce the `gravity` of the physicsWorld. Another option is to apply a force in the opposite direction to each object. If the gravity is -9.8 in the y axis, you could apply a force from +0-9.8 in the y axis to slow the object down.

EDIT: Changing the mass does not affect the speed.

Comment: mass does not alter the speed of an object falling.  You can measure the amount of force that is applied to an object,  but acceleration is constant, and acceleration is what changes the speed of an object

Comment: I just tested this, and KnightOfDragon is correct, the mass does not change the speed the object falls.

Comment: @claassenApps  Glad to hear Isaac Newton's discovery in 1687 has finally been verified!

Comment: Always happy to contribute to science!